Cannot find applications in the start menu after upgrading from 22.04
I've just upgraded Kubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04 and some applications aren't available in the start menu anymore. Apart from a couple of snap installed apps, I can't see other common applications like Thunderbird.
If I start it from the console and then pin it to the app bar, the next time I click on the pinned icon I get a different instance of the application. In the case of Thunderbird, instead of jumping into my emails, I get the screen to set up a new account.
Any idea what could be the reason and how to fix this?

Additional Info
If I type where thunderbird I get the following.
Does it mean I have thunderbird installed multiple times? How do I understand which one is the correct instance?
/usr/bin/thunderbird
/bin/thunderbird
/snap/bin/thunderbird


I fixed this by adding the following line to the /etc/zsh/zprofile file:
emulate sh -c 'source /etc/profile'

Now I can see the snap application in the application bar and pin them with no side effects.
